# Norm of some element in cyclotomic field

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I'm stuck with this question: Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $p$-th root of unity where $p$ is a prime number. Then the norm $N : \mathbb{Q}(\zeta) \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ of $(1 + \zeta^x)$ for $x \in \{ 1, ..., p-1 \}$ is odd. Why is that the case?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Use the product formula in terms of the action of the Galois group. You will get a product of terms that you can now recognize as the evaluation of the cyclotomic polynomial at some number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One should assume $p > 2$.

Consider the identity

$$1+z+ \dotsb + z^{p-1} = \prod_{j=1}^{p-1} (z-\zeta^j)$$

and take $z$ to be $-1$.

This furthermore shows that $1+\zeta^x$ is in fact a unit.

Edit: There is a much easier approach. We have

$$1+\zeta^x = \frac{1-\zeta^{2x}}{1-\zeta^x}$$

Numerator and denominator of this fraction have the same norm (since they are conjugates of each other), hence $N(1+\zeta^x)=1$.