# Kummer's Lemma and $1+\zeta$

Tags: number-theory, roots-of-unity, cyclotomic-fields

In lecture we were told to think about the following:

> **Kummer's Lemma:** Let $p$ be an odd prime and let $\zeta := e^{2\pi i / p}$. Every unit of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ is of the form $r\zeta^g$, where $r$ is real and $g$ is an integer.

This theorem says that the units of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ can be thougth as the points of the lines that pass through the vertices of an equally spaced $p$-gon centered at the origin. (Said vertices are of the form $\zeta^g$.)

However, we know that $1+\zeta$ [is a unit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1195155/norm-of-some-element-in-cyclotomic-field). But this number does not lie on one of those lines. What is wrong here?

Edit: This question seems to originate from Stewart & Tall's "Algebraic Number Theory and Fermat's Last Theorem" (4th edition), where it appears as Ex. 11.6 (p. 199).

Comment: Draw a picture! In the case $p=3$, $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/3}$, you will see that $1+\zeta$ is on the same line through the origin as $\zeta^2$. In this case we actually have $1+\zeta=-\zeta^2$, but that is specific to $p=3$. Try $p=5$ next, and *see* how the land lies. The line continues on the other side of the origin! Both the answerers do a good job IMHO (+1 to y'all).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let the odd prime number be $p=2k+1$. Consider the number
$$
w = \zeta^k(1+\zeta)\ .
$$
Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\bar w &=\overline{\zeta^k(1+\zeta)}
=\bar\zeta^k(1+\bar\zeta) 
=\zeta^{-k}(1+\zeta^{-1})
\\
&
=\zeta^{p-k}\frac 1\zeta(\zeta+1)
=\zeta^{k+1}\frac 1\zeta(\zeta+1)
=\zeta^k(\zeta+1)=w\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So $w$ is a real number, and $1+\zeta=w\;\zeta^{-k}=w\;\zeta^{k+1}$.

Comment: If $p=2k\color{blue}-1$, then $p-k=k\color{blue}-1$.  Did you mean $p=2k+1$?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the point, as i started, i wanted to have $w\zeta^k$... Then i've got $w\zeta^{-k}$, and started changing things... I will adjust!

Answer (score 2):

Geometrically:

Consider the regular $p$-gon with its center at the origin $O$ and with $A = (0,1)$, and the other points $B_n$ with coordinates corresponding to $\zeta^n$. The lines going through these points and $O$ make angles $\tau n/p$ with the positive $x$-axis, and angles $\tau/2 - \tau n/p$ with the negative $x$-axis. Because $p$ is odd, the two sets of angles together are the angles $\tau n/2p$.

For each of the points $B_n$, the location of the complex point $1+\zeta^n$ can be found by constructing a rhombus using $O$, $A$, and $B_n$ as three vertices. Call this new point $C_n$. (Think the standard picture of vector addition.)

Now $\angle AOB_n$ has a measure equal to $\frac{\tau n}{p}$, meaning $\angle OAC_n$ has half that measure (by the properties of a rhombus). But we've seen that each of the angles $\tau n/2p$ is made by one of the lines passing through the origin and one of the points $B_n$. Therefore $C_n$ must lie on a line passing through $O$ and $B_m$ for some $m \neq n$.